# Can I Feint while Swallowed Whole?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, combat-maneuver

Sethix the [Swashbuckler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=15) has been [Swallowed Whole](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=35) by a [T-Rex](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=123). In order to help cut his way out, Sethix wants to [Feint](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=48) to gain Panache, since he is a [Fencer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Styles.aspx?ID=3) Swashbuckler. **Is this something Sethix can do?** I'm aware the flat-footed condition would be redundant, but that's not the point here, perhaps Sethix has [Goading Feint](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1517), or perhaps he really doesn't care.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Technically, you can attempt to Feint against a creature that has swallowed you

From a pure mechanics standpoint, nothing prevents you from Feinting. Being Swallowed Whole imposes the Grabbed (which imposes Flat-Footed and Immobilized) condition and you are Slowed 1 . Since you're Immobilized, you can't take actions with the Move trait, and attempts to use the Manipulate action have a chance to automatically fail.

To attempt a Feint, you need to be within melee reach of the target, and that's it. The Feint action has neither the Move nor the Manipulate trait, it only has the Mental trait. As part of the Feint, you have to make a Deception check vs the targets Perception DC. This brings up the question of if you can Deceive a creature that can neither see nor hear you, but technically, Feint doesn't actually require that the target can perceive you. As far as I can tell, nothing in the rules actually prevents this, although Perception is referenced in a *lot* of places, so I may have missed something. So theoretically, you have a chance for success, and there aren't even any actual penalties to the attempt to boot.

---

**That being said, were I the DM, this would automatically fail.**

A Feint is an attempt to trick your opponent, by making a false blow or some other distraction, to try to get them to defend a location that you aren't actually attacking, in order to create an opening for you elsewhere. If a creature cannot perceive you, then you can't trick it.

Comment: I think Paizo missed an opportunity to give Feint the Visual (or Auditory) Traits.

Comment: Is there any sort of genericized line of effect thing we could be missing here? I guess Sethix still has line of sight and effect to the T-Rex, but just its stomach...

Comment: Agreed, auto-fail. What in particular is Sethix trying to mislead with his feint? The T-Rex's stomach? How much room is there in a T-Rex stomach? Surely it is a fairly constricted environment to attempt anything in...

Comment: I would rather ask my player "How exactly are you going to do that?" and let him decide it is of no use himself. Or surprise me with an answer that will make me say "OK".

Comment: @Mołot I'm all for letting players come up with creative solutions to problems, but I don't think that it's reasonable to give them a chance to do something that should be physically impossible.

Comment: @BaconyRevanant Even if they describe it in a way that totally makes sense and is possible? And you can't be sure they won't if you will not let them try.

Comment: @Mołot I think you're missing the distinction between "something that's hard to do, but theoretically possible" and "something that cannot be done, regardless of what explanation you might try to come up with".

Comment: But it *can* perceive you.  You're in its gut, after all.  It can *feel* you.  So... poke it with a stick, or adjust your weight in some deceptive  way, so that it... okay.  I got nothing with respect to what useful reaction you'd draw out of it.  Although, the panache part might just require that you fooled the thing and got it to react somehow... which, say, convincing it that it was about to get hit really hard in a particularly tender spot on its insides might indeed do.

Comment: @BenBarden Well, if you figure out a way to communicate with a creature, whos' stomach you are currently inside, that you're about to stab the inside of that stomach in a spot that is also somehow more susceptible to being stabbed than any other part, so that the creature can react to that communication in a way that allows you to stab it *even better*, feel free to let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly XD